# The case of the disappearing gargoyle

Tags: dark-souls-2-sotfs

While on a routine clean-up mission on the ramparts of [Drangleic Castle](http://darksouls.wikia.com/wiki/Drangleic_Castle), I came across a ladder by a door leading to an [Alonne knight captain](http://darksouls.wikia.com/wiki/Alonne_Knight_Captain). Having settled a disagreement with the captain I wanted to check out the open area, and was promptly attacked by a [belfry gargoyle](http://darksouls.wikia.com/wiki/Belfry_Gargoyles_(Dark_Souls_II)). At one point it was doing a swooping attack and simply continued off the platform and behind some other ramparts. Since my full armour parkour skills are sub-par I decided to wait; the miscreant was sure to return. But no such luck. And, being a beast with means of flight, no souls were forthcoming. Is there some way to come to a satisfactory solution for this conundrum?

Comment: I think it's simple glitch. You could rest at bonfire and try engaging gargoyle one more time.

Comment: Is this SotFS, or the vanilla game?

Comment: It's in SotFS...